# Black/Brown Basil

Tags: insects, herbs, basil

After noticing a few Japanese beetles on my basil plants, I used the recommended dish soap and water solution and sprayed the plants.  All 3 of them turned black or brown within a day or so.

I cut them all back, and they are doing well again, except it looks like the beetles are at it again.  It's not a terrible infestation but I hate seeing beautiful, big leaves with holes in them!

Any other recommendations as I'm hesitant to try the soap and water again.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps the place that "recommended" was assuming a differently-concentrated or formulated "dish soap" than what you used, or was one of the endless copy-and-paste sites of things that sound plausible but nobody has actually tried to see if they work as claimed. For JBs, a trap AWAY from your basil for the short term and milky spore in the lawn for long term work. Or plant some raspberries, they go for mine before everything else, I think. Grapes might be a close second.

Comment: Its possible that you sprayed during a hot day, and its burnt

Comment: I sprayed them late morning, but I don't remember how hot it was.  Thank you!